# Groovy xml selecting child node attribute based on parent mode attribute

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have an xml structure like this

```
<JJJ version="2.0" >
<Data >
 <Object class="classX">
  <k name="constname1">variable1</p>
  <k name="constname2">variable2</p>
  <k name="constname3">variable3</p>
</Object>
 <Object class="classY">
  <k name="constname1">variable11</p>
  <k name="constname2">variable12</p>
  <k name="constname3">variable13</p>
</Object>
```

I need to select ClassX node and in that value of atttribute containing constname1 (ie variable1

```
def parser = new XmlSlurper()
def mymo=records.'Data'.'Object';
def mytest =  mymo.findAll{it.@class.text()=="ClassX"};
mytest.each{
it.'p'.each{
  println  it.@name.text() +'-'+ it.text() }
 }
```

This is working. But instead of then comapring text in the loop I need to do something like this

```
def testme= mytest.'k'.find{ it.@name.text()=="constname1"}
```

This I am not getting right

However the below is right

```
      println mymo.'k'.find{it.@name.text()=="constname1"}
```

But I want to restrict selection to the node for classX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcting your xml so it's valid, gives:

```
def xml = '''<JJJ version="2.0" >
            |  <Data >
            |    <Object class="classX">
            |      <k name="constname1">variable1</k>
            |      <k name="constname2">variable2</k>
            |      <k name="constname3">variable3</k>
            |    </Object>
            |    <Object class="classY">
            |      <k name="constname1">variable14</k>
            |      <k name="constname2">variable15</k>
            |      <k name="constname3">variable16</k>
            |    </Object>
            |    <Object class="classX">
            |      <k name="constname1">variable7</k>
            |      <k name="constname2">variable8</k>
            |      <k name="constname3">variable9</k>
            |    </Object>
            |  </Data>
            |</JJJ>'''.stripMargin()

List var = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).'**'.grep { 
  it.@name == 'constname1' && it.parent().@class == 'classX'
}

assert var == [ 'variable1', 'variable7' ]
```

is that what you wanted?

Comment: Well there can be more nodes with ClassX and I need to use .findAll; however then it is not working; Basically I need to get the list of all classes which contatin classX  like `def mytest =  mymo.findAll{it.@class.text()=="ClassX"};` and then do a 'find' on that

Comment: @alexcpn Could you update your question so the example shows what you actually have and the result you require?

Comment: @alexcpn Updated my answer...  Is that closer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the correct way was

mytest.'k'.find{ it.['@name']=="constname1"}

Did similar for some other xml  Link -->[GPath Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GPath)